# Glide return Error : load failed with size

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-glide

I try to get image from url in Array list but it always return failed to load resources  so and if I use picasoo it return setting airplane  mode on has moved from android .providers .setting.systmem to android.providers .setting.global returning only read value
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource so how can I solve this error and thanks

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            Glide.with(context).load(anime.get(position).getImage_url()).into(holder.AnimeImage);


    }
```

Comment: use android tag in your question